# How do I create a C# dictionary from a json array of named lists?

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have a file that looks like this:

```
{
  "Type1":
    [
      "Value1",
      "Value2",
      "Value5"
    ],
  "Type2":
    [
      "Value4",
      "Value6",
      "Value8"
    ],
  "Type3":
    [
      "Value7",
      "Value3"
    ]
}
```

I want to convert this to an reverse dictionary of sorts, so the resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
<Value1,Type1>
<Value2,Type1>
<Value3,Type3>
<Value4,Type2>
<Value5,Type1>
<Value6,Type2>
<Value7,Type2>
<Value8,Type3>
```

The end goal is to be able to get the type of any given value (both are string type). I will get the value with a request for service, and I need to get its type for processing.

Here's what I have so far, but it seems pretty clunky -- my JSON parsing skills are more than a little rusty...

```
  public Dictionary<string, string> BuildValueMap(string pathToJson)
  {
     var jObj = LoadJsonFile(pathToJson);

     var valueMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     foreach (var node in jObj.Properties())
     {
        var type = node.Name;
        foreach (string value in node.Value)
        {
           valueMap.Add(value, type);
        }
     }
     return valueMap;
  }

  private static dynamic LoadJsonFile(string pathToJson)
  {
     using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(pathToJson))
     {
        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
     }
  }
```

Is there an easier / cleaner / more concise / overall better way to do this? TIA for any and all ideas and suggestions!!

Comment: What you have, works fine, right? You could make it less verbose and perhaps more unreadable using Linq, is that what you want? According to [help/on-topic] this might border on opinion-based or code review. Can you be more specific in what you want?

Comment: You could for example remove 9 lines by using `dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(pathToJson))`. But suggestions like that are more fit at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was just a little unsure whether this was even the correct way to perform the transformation, and I couldn't find an example anywhere. From the responses so far, I probably wouldn't change it...

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and use LINQ to process the result:

```
var valueMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json)
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(NewKey => (NewKey, kvp.Key)))
    .ToDictionary(t => t.NewKey, t => t.Key)
```